# Use NServiceBus for desktop app integration?

Tags: ipc, nservicebus, desktop-integration

Background:

- We have a bunch of Windows apps that need to be integrated.
- We think a publish-subscribe IPC
  mechanism/library would do the trick.
- Inter app Events don't need to be
  persisted;
- Not all apps are written on .NET but
  those that aren't have a plug-in
  architecture that allows for
  extending in .NET
- The apps are run by users on a
  Terminal Service environment.
- The IPC mechanism should support user
  isolation. I don't want a message
  sent by Joe's instance of App A to
  Joe's instance of App B end up on
  Sam's instance of App B.

As I understand it, this is possible by either:

- use an IPC that has user isolation
  built in (DDE)
- use a general IPC and implement user
  isolation myself (include user id in
  the messages)

Questions:

- One of the options we are thinking of
  is NServiceBus. Is anybody out there
  that used this library for this same
  problem (desktop integration) ? Is
  NServiceBus even intended to be used
  this way ? Perhaps someone that
  replaced the default transport (MSMQ)
  with something volatile ?
- Is anybody out there that actually had the same problem and resolved it with a diferent pub-sub mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

NServiceBus was built to help resolve the [Fallacies of Distributed Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing).  Given that your scenario involves several applications running on the same machine, NSB really doesn't apply here in my opinion.  Your proposed solution seems feasible given the locality of the applications.